# Does a large buffer with Socket.Receive increase the risk of a WSAENOBUFS SocketError?

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, network-programming

We are getting an error that the operation system could not allocate more TCP buffers (SocketError=WSAENOBUFS). This is basically because the machine is running out of memory.

But I was wondering if such a situation can be made worse by calling Socket.Receive with a very large buffer. Does Windows need to allocate more TCP buffers when we supply a large buffer?

Comment: When you say "very large buffer" how much are you talking about? Kilibytes? Tens of KB? Hundreds? Megabytes? Also, what is the nature of the data you transmit?

Comment: Binary data, about 100-200Mb. Normally we receive messages that are rather smallish (< 100kb). The machine is 32bit an there are several applications running on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply a large buffer, it's supplied. Windows doesn't have to allocate it: you did. There isn't much point in specifying a buffer larger than the socket receive buffer itself, as it can never be filled.

Comment: Ok, that is what I expected, only I got unsure, because the mentioned socket error cropped up exactly where such a large message was read. As the receive buffers are not part of the user memory, the memory pressure on the user side should not have caused allocation off these receive buffers to fail. 

That it is not useful to specify a buffer larger than the socket receive buffer is obvious, but at the same time it is slightly less coding if in the end one is interested in filling that entire buffer. 

Thanks for the answer!